# Beginner - what does %i do for a tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples

On the W3resource website there is a beginner [exercise #10](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-9.php)  which asks for the following:

> Write a Python program to display the examination schedule. (extract the date from exam_st_date). Go to the editor
> exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
>
> Sample Output : The examination will start from : 11 / 12 / 2014*

in the sample solution the following code is given:

```
exam_st_date = (11,12,2014)
print( "The examination will start from : %i / %i / %i"%exam_st_date)
```

what does the `%i` mean or do and how does it interact with tuples in python?

Comment: It means they're using an old string formatting method

Comment: Have you tried to run that code? It should be self-explanatory except perhaps for the fact that for output %i and %d are synonymous

Comment: `%i` is a placeholder for a signed integer decimal value.

Comment: `i` has nothing to do with tuples, per se. However since a tuple argument was given to the `%` operator, then each element of the tuple is "assigned", from left to right, to a different `%i` in the format string.

Comment: New code should use either the `format` method or f-strings rather than using the `%` operator for string formatting. `%` is still useful to know, though, for understanding how the `logging` module constructs log messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is the legacy [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) syntax.  [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) page describes the accepted formatting specifiers - `%i` formats the argument as a "signed integer decimal".

The modern equivalent is the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function, or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).

Comment: This doesn't explain what `%i` means

Comment: Heh true, I also skipped over the `%i` part when reading the question.

Comment: @Sayse See my edit.

Comment: How would the code look like if the current string formatting syntax was used?

Comment: A direct translation might look like: `print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {}".format(*exam_st_date))` or `print(f"The examination will start from : {exam_st_date[0]} / {exam_st_date[1]} / {exam_st_date[2]}")`.  If I were writing it, I would use a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) instead of a tuple, which (among other benefits) lets you use [date-aware formatting specifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), e.g. `print(f"The examination will start from : {exam_st_date:%d / %m / %Y}")`